# How to group by only by one field in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have this query

```
select id, order_number, order_date from employee_trip_orders
group by id, order_number, order_date
```

But, i would like to use group by with only one field like

```
select id, order_number, order_date from employee_trip_orders
group by order_date
```

But this give me "not group by expression" error. How can i group only one column?
Thanks in advance

**Existing data:**

```
id   order_number  order_date

1      553         22.01.2015

2      141         15.07.2019

3      142         28.02.2020

4     1412         22.01.2015
```

**Expected result:**

```
1   553     22.01.2015

4   1412    22.01.2015

2   141     15.07.2019

3   142     28.02.2020
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Existing and expected result are same, only the order is different. It should be `order by order_date`

Comment: I think you might be confusing `group by` with `order by`

Comment: What is the expected result in case there is one more entry in sample data as `1      887         01.01.2016` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use columns in `SELECT`, if you are not using the same in `Group By`.

And if you want to use the columns which are not there in `Group by`, then you will have to use `Aggregation Functions`.

EDIT: Referring to the expected results, i think you want to use `Order by`

```
select id, order_number, order_date from employee_trip_orders
order by order_date,id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can.  You just need aggregation functions for *all* other columns:

```
select id, max(order_number), max(order_date)
from employee_trip_orders
group by id;
```

The `max()` is just an example of the aggregation functions you want.  Your question is not clear on what you really want in the result set.

EDIT:

You seem to want `order by`, not `group by`:

```
select eto.*
from employee_trip_orders eto
order by order_date, id;
```

Comment: @Vytsalo . . . You seem to want `order by`, not `group by`.

Comment: I don't need a sort i need a group by expression

Comment: @Vytsalo . . . According to the question that you *asked*, you want `ORDER BY`.  If you have a different question, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.